# Android eclipse DDMS - Can't access data/data/ on phone to pull files

Tags: android, eclipse

While testing my apps, I use emulators and my own phone to see if everything is working ok.  My apps are also writing data to shared preferences and a text file.

I can pull the data from my emulators through the `DDMS` in eclipse so I can read the data files on my computer, but when I try to open those folders through the `DDMS` on my phone, nothing happens.  I click the data folder and nothing happens.

My phone is rooted.  Is there any way I could pull the files from my phone?  I know that Android keeps these folders private, but there must be a way.  The emulator is just *way* too slow.

Comment: how to do this on a *non-rooted* phone?

Comment: I don't think it's possible considering you'll need to change the file-system permissions on those files/folders.  This can't be done without a rooted device.

Answer (score 160, accepted):

On **rooted** device you can do this:

1. Open cmd
2. Type `adb shell`
3. `su`
4. Press 'Allow' on device
5. `chmod 777 /data /data/data /data/data/com.application.package/data/data/com.application.package/*`
6. Go to the DDMS view in Eclipse

After this you should be able to browse the files on the device.

To get the databases:

7. `chmod 777 /data/data/com.application.package/databases /data/data/com.application.package/databases/*`

---

If it returns `permission denied` on `su`

Go to `Settings` > `Developer Options` > `Root access` > `Apps and ADB`

Comment: Finally....this works!  Almost one year later and peceps comes through.  So I'm guessing this problem has to do with the file system permissions?

Comment: yes, it is a protection to prevent some application messing with other application files.

Comment: Hi peceps, im able to see the db file in databases folder, but unable to pull file from there...Im getting "Failed to pull selection" error in console. I just like to see the db file. I tried restarting PC, Eclipse and device... bt no use. pls let me know how i can pull file nw..

Comment: I rooted my phone now I see nothing in DDMS. I can see through `adb shell` though.

Comment: @Praveenb, I had same problem, but then I repeated above chmod command with additional folders: /data/data/com.application.package/databases /data/data/com.application.packages/databases/*

Comment: @peceps : My phone is not rooted. The command  in Step 3 work does not work for me. It says permission denied. There is no 'Allow' in the device.

Comment: @peceps : You have given the process for accessing data/data on a rooted phone. But is there a way to do that in non-rooted phone or is perfectly secure?

Comment: @Ashwin I don't think there is a way of doing this on non-rooted phone.

Comment: Hi @peceps, I'm able to access the /data folder using the Terminal Emulator app but not `adb shell su` due to "permission denied" error - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18226210/cannot-open-data-folder-in-a-rooted-android-device

Comment: @fuzzybee try only 'su'. See if you get a popup on the device asking you to allow the command.

Comment: I get this on my non-rooted Galaxy S3: `/system/bin/sh: su: not found`.

Comment: In developer options you may set Root Access to ADB

Comment: use `chmod -R 777 /data/data/` to apply this command recursively

Comment: @damular on my rooted Xperia Arc S I get:  BAD MODE  with -R

Comment: I get "su: not found" when I try to run su after "adb shell". (I am using a non-rooted phone)

Comment: I can't understand why this is the accepted answer and has so many upvotes!? Yes, I suppose technically it will allow me to drill down in to data/data/... and see my databases, but the permissions don't allow me to pull my database off the phone which is the crux of the question

Comment: @SimonH on rooted devices you can pull the database also, just do chmod 777 /data/data/com.application.package/databases/ chmod 777 /data/data/com.application.package/databases/*

Comment: @peceps I appreciate you taking the time to answer my comment. I've now gone a different route and installed Root Explorer (ok it cost me a couple of quid!) which allows me to copy the database out if the root folder and place it somewhere where I can get to it easily.

Answer (score 6):

No one seems to understand that a retail Nexus One even after being rooted still will not let you browse the file system using DDMS File Explorer. We are talking about real phones here and not the emulator. If you happen to have a Nexus One Developer Phone you can browse the file system using DDMS Filer Explorer, but a retail Nexus One that has been rooted you can't. Got it?

So I hope that answers the question of not being able to use the DDMS File Explorer to browse the file system of a rooted retail Nexus One. After rooting a retail Nexus One there is still something that remains to be done to use DDMS to use the File Explorer to browse the phones File System. I don't know what it is. Maybe someone else knowns.

Comment: Amen, brother.  I'd sure like to know what the hell Root Explorer is doing to get in there....

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 4):

If gives **"permission denied"** on adb shell -> su...

Some ROMs are running adbd daemon in secure mode (adbd has no root access and su command does not even show permission ask dialog on the device). In this case you will get "permission denied" when you try cmd -> adb shell -> su. The solution I've found is one app from the famous modder Chainfire called Adbd Insecure.

Comment: In CyanoGenMod, go to setup-->Developer options-->root access    and change to 'adb and apps' (default is 'apps')

Answer (score 3):

You must edit permission of data folder.

I use "Root Explorer" (see market) app on root mode.

On top select "Monunted as r/w"

then press over data folder (long click) and find Permission option

Have a somenthing like that

```
        read    write  execute
```

User

Group

Others

Make sure that "Others" have a check for read

Then go Eclpse and try again.

Sorry about my english,I hope can help you.

Comment: This is extremely unwise!

Answer (score 2):

To set permission on the `data` folder and all it's subfolders and files:

Open command prompt from the ADB folder:

```
>> adb shell
>> su
>> find /data -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
```

Answer (score 2):

**Much simpler** than `messing around with permissions` in the android FS (which always feels like
 a hack for me - because i believe there must be a kind of `integrated way`) is just to:

**Allow `ADB root access` and `Restart the deamon` with `root permissions`.**

1. First be sure that ADB can have root access on your device (or emulator):
   (`Settings` -> `Developer Options` -> `Root-Access for ADB` or `Apps & ADB`.
2. Restart the ADB-Service with root-permissions:
   Open a `command prompt` and type: `adb.exe root`
3. Restart ADM (Android Device Manager):
   `Enjoy` browsing all files
4. To negate this process:
   Type `adb.exe unroot` in your `command prompt`.

Comment: @János Maybe its related because i'm using CyanogenMod

Answer (score 1):

Event though it's a bit too late to try to answer this I'll leave what worked for me.

Peceps's solution didn't work because the SuperUser app didn't allow "shell" to have root access. So my solution is to directly use another app like RootExplorer and browse the folders from it.

Comment: I have to say that of all the answers listing adb commands, changing permissions and fiddling about with DDMS that has meant me wasting a whole evening (that I could have spent watching football)... this has been the only, best and simplest solution that has actually allowed me to get to read my database. Much respect and thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If it retures "**permission denied**" on adb shell -> **su**...

Go to "Developer Options" -> Root access -> "Apps and ADB"

Comment: I am using HTC and can't seem to find Root access in developer option

Answer (score 0):

When I say file system I meant the whole file system. But you can only browse part of the file system on a retail phone, perhaps even most of file system but not ./data. Sorry for any confusion this may have caused.

This is alarming to me because I have a rooted my retail Nexus One and a developer/unlocked Nexus One. Since I rooted my retail Nexus One I can't figure out why I can't browse the whole file system like I can on my developer Nexus One.

Answer (score -3):

If you NEED to do it on your phone, I use a terminal emulator and standard linux commands.

Example:

1. su
2. cd data
3. cd com.yourappp
4. ls or cd into cache/shared_prefs

http://www.appbrain.com/app/android-terminal-emulator/jackpal.androidterm

Comment: No you don't need to do that.

Comment: @ Octavian - You're telling me that you can pull files from a real phone, not an emulator, through file explorer in the DDMS?  Whenever I click on the "data" folder in file explorer, it does not populate the tree.  Your answer below only works for me if I'm using an emulator, not a real phone.

Comment: If you need to access the data folder then you have to use rooted devices.