# Couldn't find Application Package Name in Android device

Tags: android

So I make an Android app with package name com.xxx.xxx. I know that any installed app will create a folder in Android/Data/com.xxx.xxx. But my case is I can't find my application package name in that directory after I install it. Am I missing something?

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ceria.tuntun"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

</manifest>
```

Comment: post your android manifest file code..

Comment: It's actually inside data/data directory. Do you see any other folders where you are looking for your package?

Comment: Wait a sec, having trouble to add the manifest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which device r u using? You cannot see the application package in most of the devices because those do not have access to the internal storage if the app is installed in phone memory. You can access only `SDCard`.

Comment: I am using noon rooted device. Samsung Galaxy note.

Comment: You can check your database by rooting your device and open command prompt and change the directory to ur platform-tools folder of android SDK and enter the following lines.Type 'adb shell'
su
Press 'Allow' on device
chmod 777 /data /data/data /data/data/com.application.pacakage /data/data/com.application.pacakage/*
Go to the DDMS view in Eclipse. Please check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867379/android-eclipse-ddms-cant-access-data-data-on-phone-to-pull-files

Answer (score 2):

Installed app wont necessary create a folder in `Android/Data`. There only the cache files are stored of your app, and that too if you have programmed your app to do so. By default the apps are stored in `Internal memory` in `/data/data` which can be accessed only if u have a rooted phone and a file browser for root users.

Comment: so there won't be no way for me to access that and see my database? because I need to see my database

Comment: Is there any way to install application to external memory?

Comment: Beginning with API Level 8 you can allow your app to be installed on external storage using android:installLocation="preferExternal". Take a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html

Answer (score 0):

the app is installed into the phone memory and not the SD Card by default. only the SD card files can be seen in an unrooted phone.

To install to SD card add this code to the manifest file.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:installLocation="preferExternal"
... >
```

Comment: I have tried your solution but still can't find my application package name in the directory