# Cannot open /data folder in a rooted Android device

Tags: android, filesystems, adb, terminal-emulator, rooted-device

My HTC Sensation is rooted (I can see the SuperUser app; I can `su` using the Terminal Emulator app; I was able to install Android Stock ROM Cyanogenmod).

I'm not able to open the `/data` folder using either ADT or `adb shell su` (permission denied) or File Expert app.

What can I do to open the folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer and solution:

1. As for access the `adb shell`, I need to enable "Root access" for
   ADB in "Developer options" (this apply for stock Android 4.0.4 by
   Cyanogenmod but the same option could be present somewhere else in
   your phone)
2. As for File Expert, the "Root Explorer" functionality is
   only available in their paid version

   - I'm going to use ES File Explorer
     and the likes
3. I haven't found a solution for access through ADT's
   Device Manager yet but I'm happy having 2 options above

Comment: Hi eric, I am using ES File Explorer but still cannot see the contents of the data file. The device is completely rooted and verified, Running Bluetsacks 2 on PC

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed supersu like apk. When you do 'su' in the shell, there might be a notification on screen asking that if you agree the program to run 'su'.

You have to grant the permission.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing if your mobile  is root then u can't access anything without the SU permission just take the permission by @kiNGUSER (app) then u can give access to your file manager