# can't see database in DDMS of geny motion

Tags: android, ddms, genymotion

I am using genymotion emulator as I am fedup with useless android emulator.

Genymotion is fine but when I create a database it is not visible in DDMS folder, now I am confused whether it is created or not.

Can anyone give idea on how to overcome this issue.

Thanks in advance
Siva

Comment: Check also this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867379/android-eclipse-ddms-cant-access-data-data-on-phone-to-pull-files/8896049#8896049

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directory explorer is currently not working with Genymotion VMs.
You can find it via `adb shell`

You can access the database directory of your app in command line :

```
 $ su
 # cd /data/data/[your.package.name]/databases
```

Comment: Thanks eyal for your reply... please tell me where I need to fire those commands in geny motion shell of adb shell.

Comment: There is nothing special to Genymotion actually. adb shell is the command you use to open a shell on your Android device. When you see your device on DDMS, you can run adb shell.