# I cannot view any folders (or it shows it as empty) in my ddms - at data/data - even though the file path saves to that location

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ddms

How can I fix this so that I can see a) my text file that is saved in data/data and b) a database that I have saved in that location?

Comment: Make sure you have selected the correct emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On **rooted** device you can do this:

1. Open cmd
2. Type '`adb shell`'
3. `su`
4. `chmod 777 /data /data/data /data/data/com.application.pacakage /data/data/com.application.pacakage/*`
5. Press 'Allow' on device
6. Go to the DDMS view in Eclipse

After this you should be able to browse the files on the device.

---

If it returns `permission denied` on su

Go to `Settings` > `Developer Options` > `Root access` > `Apps and ADB`

Answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8896049/1991579)

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly the answer I was looking for and what I need to do.