# Simple save file doesn't show in ddms and can't find the file on my device?

Tags: android

I am trying this simple save .txt on an Android phone but I can't find the file with ddms->file explorer;  Data folder is empty/not expandable (so data/data/[package name]/files is not shown). 
Also on my Android device (moto G) I can't find the file. But the log shows the file should be saved :

```
saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            // Create a file in the Internal Storage

            String fileName = "MyFile.txt";
            String content = "hello world";

            FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
            try {
                storageDir = new File(
                    Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES
                    ),
                    getAlbumName()
            );
                outputStream = openFileOutput( fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                outputStream.write(content.getBytes());
                outputStream.close();

                Log.d(SAVE_PROCESS, "File directory: "+storageDir +" File name: "+fileName + " directory "+getFilesDir());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d(SAVE_PROCESS, "File not saved");
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8896049/4211264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had same problem.
I think your file is in below path.
In eclipse :- `Open File Explorer -> mnt -> shell -> emulated -> 0 -> DIRECTORY_PICTURES.`

I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

App private directory `/data/data/[package name]` is accessible to your app only, but it's not accessible to other apps, and it's generally NOT accessible from ADB/DDMS/through your phone USB port.

If you root your phone, or install an engineering build of Android, you can run command `adb root` from PC, or command `stop adbd; setprop service.adb.root 1; start adbd` from root shell on Android, this will restart ADB with root permissions, then you will be able to access directories under `/data/data`.

Or just save your file to SD card, it's accessible from everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You are saving the file in the Public external folder for images, not in your app folder (which cannot be accessed, as already answered). You should check in a path like `/storage/emulated/legacy/Pictures` (might be slightly different depending on your phone)

Comment: no i am not using storageDir in the exactly code just for the log message.