# Not able to see database file in data -> data with DDMS perspective. I want to see SQLite Database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-studio

Under Android Device Monitor -> Under my device -> under data -> there is only one file with default.prop
Pls help me with this, Using Android Studio
N one more thing i wanted to ask , Even in my workspace not able to see any file or folder like database or .db file anywhere.

Can Anybody Help me out with this 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Android eclipse DDMS - Can't access data/data/ on phone to pull files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867379/android-eclipse-ddms-cant-access-data-data-on-phone-to-pull-files)  Maybe peceps's answer can help you.  Firstly confirm your devices are rooted, then use su and chmod to set permission.

If you just want to see SQLite Database,I think [Stetho](http://facebook.github.io/stetho/) will be a good choice. It can see database by chrome.

Comment: Please add some content from the link.

Comment: Thanks  :) But i dun think so i need to root my phone as m trying to find database file in ADM( And Device mngr) , to see database by chrome or Firefox , First i need to access my database file. please help me to find that database file first  @Gaurav setia