# how to check the structure of the SQLite database using Emulator and a Real device?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

After run the project through mobile In the android device monitor only i see the (data) but it does not show  the hierarchy means data->data.

Comment: DDMS -> file explorer -> data -> data -> see your package name -> databases -> here your . Follow this Path. Pull the database to your desktop and Mozilla is providing the SqiliteDatabse plugin.After installing the plugin you can paste your database there.Hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks j ..after going to file explorer i can see only data ..remaining hierarchy part is not showing ,,after run the project in my mobile

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "hierarchy"?

Comment: DDMS -> file explorer -> data->(upto this i can see )

Comment: This is not an answer to my question. What exactly do you want to see?

Comment: i have created the sqlite database and insert some data ..i want to see how it stored ...

Comment: @DipankarDutta: you have to run the project in emulator.you can not see the db which is run by your phone.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to view your database, then you need to give the path to store the database file in the constructor, as shown below.

```
    public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    //Database helper class constructor...
        public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, context.getExternalFilesDir(DATABASE_NAME)
                    .getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }



        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        }


        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }
}
```

After doing this you can view the database with the help of DDMS.

Hope this is helpful :)

Comment: still same problem ...

Comment: after selecting the data->(not able to see the data or hierarchy)

Comment: @DipankarDutta: Right now your database file is stored in external storage location not in data folder. data folder will open only for emulator not for phones. So we need to store the db file in external path and you need to check in "mnt->shell->emulated->0->Android->data->your package name" this is where I used to find the db in moto g first generation. Hope this helps:)

Comment: Thank you very much dear.....now i can see the structure......again thanks a lot...

Comment: sorry ,i dont have more reputation to upvote your ans ..but i marked as a correct ans. someone has edited and given the votes i think ..thanks a lot ...you really help me a lot..

Answer (score -1):

You can't access the database via Android Device Monitor except on a rooted device as in the https://stackoverflow.com/a/8896049/4758255.

But you can use [Stetho](http://facebook.github.io/stetho/):

> Stetho is a sophisticated debug bridge for Android applications. When
>   enabled, developers have access to the Chrome Developer Tools feature
>   natively part of the Chrome desktop browser. Developers can also
>   choose to enable the optional dumpapp tool which offers a powerful
>   command-line interface to application internals.

Comment: You can inspect emulator's databases fine via Device Monitor

Comment: @cricket_007: Did you read the op question btw?. Op didn't ask about emulator and my answer didn't either.

Comment: "Through mobile" is not clear enough, IMO

Comment: i am testing the app in real device..and i am using android studio 2.2.3

Answer (score -1):

I'd recommend using the [Android Debug Database](https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Android-Debug-Database) library. It's much easier to use, with minimal setup.
Although you can not access it via your phone, but through your browser instead.